# Getting The Value of Third or Fourth Level JSON Key

Tags: python, json

I am trying to write a python test based around the value of a third or fourth level JSON key in Python and can't figure out how.

Here is an example of the JSON code:

```
{  
    "status":"Success",
    "firstID":"12345",
    "errorDetails":{  
        "message":null,
        "additionalinfo":{  
        }
    },
    "randomID":"678910",
    "response":[  
        {  
            "aid":"123456",
            "outcome":"Good",
            "stausMessage":"success",
            "additionalInfo":{  
                "successes":[  
                    {  
                        "aid":"097c9e28",
                        "additionalProperties":{  
                            "details":[  
                                "Successful call"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {  
                        "aid":"097c9e28",
                        "additionalProperties":{  
                            "details":[  
                                "Successful call"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {  
                        "aid":"097c9e28",
                        "additionalProperties":{  
                            "details":[  
                                "Successful call"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {  
                        "aid":"097c9e28",
                        "additionalProperties":{  
                            "details":[  
                                "Successful call"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "errors":[  

                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "additionalInfo":{  

    }
}
```

This json is part of a REST service repsonse called response. I can access the second level keys using the following code:

```
        a_id = int(self.response.json()['response'][0]['aid'])
        assert_that(aid).is_between(123450, 123499)
```

However I can't figure out how to reach the lower-level keys named "aid" which is equal to 097c9e28.

Comment: Tell us what does `a_id` should contain, a single value or an array of inner `a_id(s)`

Comment: A single value (a string).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to drill further, the fourth level for example is under `['additionalInfo']['success']`, to access it you need to use `['response'][0]['additionalInfo']['successes'][0]['aid']`, where `0` is the index.

For example `['response'][0]['additionalInfo']['successes'][0]` gives you the following result:

```
{'aid': '097c9e28', 'additionalProperties': {'details': ['Successful call']}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I swore I tried the same thing but it wouldn't run for me. I guess you don't need an index on 'additionalInfo' since there is always one success below it, right?

Comment: You don't, in your data under `additionalInfo` you have `successes` and `errors`, and under `successes` you have a list of itens, so you need the index.

Answer (score 1):

Quite uqly but if you want one-liner it would be this:

```
a_id = int(self.response.json()["response"][0]["additionalInfo"]["successes"][0]["aid"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
import json
resp = json.loads("""
{  
    "status":"Success",
    "firstID":"12345",
    "errorDetails":{  
        "message":null,
        "additionalinfo":{  
        }
    },
    "randomID":"678910",
    "response":[  
        {  
            "aid":"123456",
            "outcome":"Good",
            "stausMessage":"success",
            "additionalInfo":{  
                "successes":[  
                    {  
                        "aid":"097c9e28",
                        "additionalProperties":{  
                            "details":[  
                                "Successful call"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {  
                        "aid":"097c9e28",
                        "additionalProperties":{  
                            "details":[  
                                "Successful call"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {  
                        "aid":"097c9e28",
                        "additionalProperties":{  
                            "details":[  
                                "Successful call"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {  
                        "aid":"097c9e28",
                        "additionalProperties":{  
                            "details":[  
                                "Successful call"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "errors":[  

                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "additionalInfo":{  
    }
}
""")

a_id = resp.get('response', [])[0].get("additionalInfo").get("successes")[0].get("aid", "")
print(a_id)
```